# How does a current carrying loop in a uniform magnetic field $\vec{B}$ behave?

Tags: electromagnetism, torque

The torque on the loop about *any* axis parallel to the plane of the loop is $\vec\tau = \vec\mu \ \times \vec B$. 
If this is true about any axis, then how would such a loop actually behave in a magnetic field? (More specifically, about which axis would it rotate?)

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is the torque as a vector
Its component about any axis with unit vector $\mathbf n$ is $\Gamma\cdot\mathbf n$. There is a unique axis orthogonal to both $\mu$ and $\mathbf B$ about which the torque is maximum.

Comment: What is $\mathbf{n}$?